# How to adjust masonry columns on box expand without adjust entire structure

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I have a wall of boxes created by a wordpress loop that uses jquery masonry. Each box contains a thumb and I hide the information about each image and want to expand each box vertically using jquery on hover. My problem is I dont want to overlay content on another box and I could only figure out how to adjust the entire masonry on hover which causes problems when the reloading of masonry causes the hovered box to be in a different spot. So I need to only make the the box's underneath the hovered box in its' column move down without changing the format of the rest of the masonry structure if that makes any sense. You can see an example of what I have so far in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YD7GU/).

Also I tried to give the hovered box a "fixed" position with jquery in an attempt to lock it in place but the masonry reload changes it right back to "absolute" but I think I'm on to something there.

Answer (score 0):

I use CSS3 actually.

```
 .box{
transition: all 300 ease;
-moz-transition: all 300 ease; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: all 300 ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: all 300 ease ; /* Opera */
}
.box:hover{
transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
-moz-transform: scale(1.2,1.2); /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(1.2,1.2); /* Opera */
}
```

if you don't want scale set new height in .box:hover. This will work. I think you may have to set a z-index so it's above the other boxes on hover.

You can use Jquery .height() to return the height if your boxes aren't the same size. Then you can use that to set the css of the hover to say height * 1.2 for 20% relative increase.

Then get the value of the increase

```
heightMoved = height * 0.2;
```

Then move the other boxes down.

```
boxesBelowTopPosition = $(".box").css("top")
movDown = boxesBelowTopPosition + heightMoved;
```

Then on the Jquery hover event add .css("top", moveDown) to boxes in that colomun. Rough idea

Comment: That's a cool technique but I'm looking to move the box under it down instead of overlapping content on top of another box. I was able to do this kind of by reloading the masonry on hover but it's messy. I just want the box underneath the hovered box to move down when the one on top is expanded.

Comment: You'll have to do it in Jquery by changing the TOP for each item below it since they are Absolute positioned elems.